# Adobe CQ5 parsys component is not visible

Tags: aem

I am using AEM. I created page and  added parsys component to the template - in body.jsp

```
<cq:include path="par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
```

But I can not edit, use it . In rendered html of page it's empty div,  and also absents script for sidekick

> CQ.WCM.launchSidekick("/content/mywebsite/en/products",
>               {propsDialog: "/libs/foundation/components/page/dialog",
>                  locked: false locked: false
>                });

so sidekick is also invisible on that page, I added a few other components  from foundation/components - they are visible. 
How can I make parsys visible?

Comment: Please format any code in your question. Also, you don't sem to be asking a question. I assume your question is How do you make that visible?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you forgot to include the init.jsp

Try putting the following at the top of your JSP File:

`<cq:include script="/libs/wcm/core/components/init/init.jsp"/>`